# Is GUN a good option for big data?

Tags: gun

I have a data that is more than 1 million records.

1. What kind of performance can I get with GUN? Where can I see
   benchmark?
2. How much data can GUN store?

Answer (score 3):

Performance benchmarks and speed are here: https://gun.eco/docs/100000-ops-sec-in-IE6-on-2GB-Atom-CPU

Using the Radix Storage Engine, the amount of data is only limited by your hardware or hosting provider. See an early demo of RAD: https://youtu.be/x_WqBuEA7s8